# HTML <lable> displaying Java String with <strong> </strong> tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I read a String from a DB in Java that contains a paragraph and this paragraph contains <strong>a Word or Pharse</strong> tags. I simply read it from the database and displays in a html <label> or html <p> . The problem is that it shows <strong>a Word or Pharse</strong> without bold facing the Word or Phrase.

```
class MyClass{
  final String paraFromDb= "hello <strong>world</strong>";
}

<p>#{MyClass.paraFromDb}</p>;
```

This displays:
hello <strong>world</strong>

expected:
hello **world**

I manipulated the String replacing < > with &lt ; and &gt ; but still the string displays in browser with &lt ; strong&gt ;

What do I need to do in the java string so it would display the expected result?

Here is the actual component where the string containing HTML tags is placed.

<p:galleria value="#{galleriaBean.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" transitionInterval = "5000" circular="true" autoPlay="true">
<p:graphicImage name="img/#{image.name}" alt="Image Description for #{image.name}" title="#{image.name}"/>
#{image.description}

**image.description** is the string that brings in the string containing HTML tags <strong>

Comment: You should read up on the concept of String escaping, and HTML escaping specifically. Without knowing what tools you are using to display the HTML, we can't really help you further.

Comment: how are the HTML tags raw from the database? Are all "<" represented as "&lt;" and such? if yes, they are encoded before storing in database and you need to decode them. Be careful about storing HTML in a database and injecting it straight in a web page, it is an open door to future problems (XSS attacks etc)

Comment: Yes I agree with Kaddath. So that's why I tried replacing the < and > characters in the string after reading from DB with &lt; and &gt; yet then it shows &lt;strong&gt; in the HTML page.

Comment: Then it seems that your templating system escapes the HTML tags automatically, this is often done by frameworks because it is a serious risk as I said above, this is why we have things like markdown in forums to allow formatting while keeping HTML tags disabled. You should add details about the tools you are using to the question

Comment: We have an Oracle DB where the data stored. Using JPA to read the data and then displays in pages built using JSF/PrimeFaces. In fact the above said Java String is displayed in <p> or <lable> within a p:galleria component. Here is the full code block.

Comment: <p:galleria value="#{galleriaBean.images}" var="image" panelWidth="500" panelHeight="313" transitionInterval = "5000" circular="true" autoPlay="true">
        <p:graphicImage name="img/#{image.name}" alt="Image Description for #{image.name}" title="#{image.name}"/>
        <p style="font-size:21px;line-height:140%">#{image.description}</p>
      </p:galleria>
image.descrption is the string concerned.